# How to pass form input fields to another component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React to create a to-do-list app, and no back-end is involved at this stage. Currently I have two components, `Type` and `ListTable`. `Type` is a form component and `ListTable` is a table component that displays data stored in `this.state`.

What I want to achieve is, after I type in form, click `submit` button in `Type` component, the `state` data in `Type` will pass as `props` to `ListTable` component, and table data will change accordingly. But I do not know how to do this, instead, I add an additional button `refresh` in `ListTable` component, to call `onSubmitt` function in `Type` component. This ways works but not quite decent I reckon.

Here is my code https://codepen.io/heiweigou/pen/vRKjzR?editors=0010

Comment: please put code and not just the codepen in the question make it clear what exactly your asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would come up with a different component architecture here. You see, your `ListTable` is a child `Type` component, even though that is not quite the best approach. 
Create a new component, which will be the parent of both, e.g.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = { todos: [] };
      this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
   }

   addTodo(todo) {
      this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, todo] })
   }
   ...
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
           <ListTable todos={this.state.todos} /> //passing todos
           <Type addTodo={this.addTodo} /> //passing a addTodo function
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

You can pass your `Type` component a function to update the `ParentComponent`'s state, and pass that state to `ListTable` component to render your todos. 
And `Type` component's `onSubmit` function should only update its parent's component state, should not return anything.

```
onSubmit() {
   this.props.addTodo(this.state);
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
Remove `onClick` handler from `Task`'s add button and add onSubmit handler to the form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

And declare this handler like so:

```
handleFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.addTodo(this.state);
}
```

Your `ListTable's table` function should also loop through `props.todos` rather than state.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should nest `Type` inside of `ListTable`. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: I would still try to keep these two separate (the form and the list) and have the parent component above. Good luck with your work! :)